# Insertion Sort - Specific Array O(n^(7/4))

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, insertion

I'm looking for an Array of n digits, that will be sorted using Insertion Sort in time of O(n^(7/4)).
What kind of Array, as a function of n, will give me such running time?
As an example, it can be an array which is half (or more) sorted and half not, or sorted back-words, or whatever.

Hope it's clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: Not clear. OS system, coding language, example what you are looking for? Check also SO sister sites if your question suits better [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: I think this question is better suited to [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) SO sister site